# How to edit two field have the same domain at the same time in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, fields-attributes, domains, relates

I have two layers (Parcel and Building ) with fields that have the same domain, for example ;

1. **layer (Parcel)** has fields with names ("Building status", "Land Use") with domains (100,101) in parallel.
2. **layer (Building)** have the same fields in (Parcel) layer with same domains

I want to edit the attribute in the (Parcel) layer with no need to go to the (Building) layer and edit the same fields with the same attributes.

Is there any way to get these fields related to automatic editing?

Comment: Is the data regularly updated by the users or is it a one-time process?

Comment: @YogeshChavan yes, it is on time process

Comment: Finish with buildings and transfer their attributes to parcels using spatial join.

Comment: @FelixIP Spatial join will disable the domains and all fields will be string which is not suitable for the Geodatabase.

I want any updates i make in (Parcel) layer will automate updated in (Building) layer with the same field with same domains .

Comment: I did small experiment. Short integer field (with domain) does not change to text description after join, although it might look like text. Check field properties.